# Tensorflow - ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor when creating a dataset from a split array

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

So I have this weird bug when I create a tf.data.Dataset from tensor slices like so

```
train = AB.copy()
test = train.sample(2000)
train = train[~(train.A.isin(test.A))]
x_train = train.A_image.to_numpy()
y_train = train.Label.to_numpy()
x_test = test.A_image.to_numpy()
y_test = test.Label.to_numpy()
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({'image_input': x_train, 'label_input': y_train}, y_train))
ds_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({'image_input': x_test, 'label_input': y_test}, y_test))
```

now the creation of `dataset` works
but `ds_test` throws this error in the title.
I checked they're valid arrays, same shape.
And sometimes when I restart runtime this same code works

What could be the issue here?

thanks for looking at it!

edit:converting x_test first to a list and then to an array works.

Comment: maybe x_test happens to be an empty array?

Comment: no it's not, it's thousands of examples just like x_train, as I added in the edit when I do to_list and then wrap np.array(x_test) it works.

Comment: It would be better if you can show something reproducible with some dummy data.

Comment: I see, I'll try to come up with something @Frightera